# Accrued interest

Tags: algebra-precalculus, finance

I know how to calculate accrued interest over time on an initial amount. However, my assignment has me artificially adding additional sums intermittently. I'm curious if there is a formula to do that. The specific task is to calculate:
$\$7000$ is invested at the beginning of each year for $25$ years with an annual interest of $7$%. Find the sum of the payments over the entire investment period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be handled simply with a geometric series.  Let $P$ be the amount invested every year, $i$ be the interest rate, and $N$ be the number of years of the investment period.  Then treat each investment at the beginning of the year separately.  Thus, the sum $S$ is

$$S = P\left (1+i\right)^n + P\left (1+i\right)^{n-1} + \cdots P\left (1+i\right)$$

This assumes that we are evaluating the sum at the end of a year.  Using the formula for a geometric series, I get

$$S=P \left(1+i\right) \frac{\left(1+i\right)^n-1}{i} $$

Plug in $P=\$7000$, $i=0.07$, $n=25$.  I get $S \approx \$ 473735$.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, one can calculate the present value of a set of periodic payments, discounted at that period interest rate.

This is explained in section "**13.1.3 A Closed Form for the Annuity Value**" section of the "*July 25, 2013 draft of the complete class text*" of the **MIT course "Mathematics for Computer Science"** (6.042/18.062J Spring 2013)

That class materials page is currently available at http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.042/spring13/class-material.shtml and the direct link PDF file (a 9.5 Megabytes file, with a "Creative Commons" license) is available at http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.042/spring13/mcs.pdf

Quoting from the page 468 of that book:

> **13.1.3 A Closed Form for the Annuity Value**
>
> Using equation 13.2, we can derive a simple formula for V, the value
>   of an annuity that pays m dollars at the start of each year for n
>   years.
>
> $$V = m\bigg(\frac{1 - x^n}{1-x}\bigg)$$
>   $$=m \bigg(\frac{1 + p - (1/(1 +p))^{n - 1}}{p}\bigg)$$

For the above formula, in the section "13.1.1 The Future Value of Money" (on pages 466-467), it is explained that:

- $m$ stands for the periodic payment value (7,000 USD in the OP example)
- $p$ is the interest rate (7% in this case)
- $x$ stands for 1/(1 + $p$)
- $n$ stands for the number of periods (25 in this case).

So, applying the formula to the OP example we would have:

$$V =7000 \bigg(\frac{1 + 0.07 - (1/(1 +0.07))^{25 - 1}}{0.07}\bigg) \approx \$87,285.34 $$

**EDIT #2**:

The above \$87,285.34 value is the [Present Value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Present_value) (as the Wikipedia article for "Present Value" says, it's the "*future amount of money that has been discounted to reflect its current value, as if it existed today*").

If we wanted the [Future Value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Future_value) instead (quoting Wikipedia again, "*the nominal future sum of money that a given sum of money is "worth" at a specified time in the future assuming a certain interest rate*"), then we could simply do $ \$87,285.34 \times (1 + 0.07)^{25}$ and we would reach the \$473,735 value that Ron Gordon has arrived to, in his answer. **:)**

**EDIT #1**: The book gives an example of calculating V (Present Value) :

> Equation 9.5 is much easier to use than a summation with dozens of
>   terms. For example, what is the real value of a winning lottery ticket
>   that pays \$50,000 per year for 20 years? Plugging in m = \$50,000, n =
>   20, and p = 0.08 gives V = \$530,180. So because payments are deferred,
>   the million dollar lottery is really only worth about a half million
>   dollars!

Comment: Investing $\$7000$ per year for 25 years without any interest provides $\$175000$.

Comment: @RonGordon Thanks for the feedback :-) I just edited my answer with an example also taken from the MIT book. I think that you are giving the "future value" while the MIT book formula and example  gives the "present value"

Comment: OK, I see where you are coming from: the MIT result is mine divided by $(1+i)^n$.

Comment: @RonGordon Exactly! :-) I just edited my answer (again) to try to make that difference clear.